# How to move redmine to a sub-URI with nginx as a proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, redmine

I want to put redmine (listening on localhost:3000 standalone passenger) behind nginx, serving from `http://domain.com/redmine` with this simple nginx config:

```
server {
    location /redmine/ {                                                                                                                                                         
        proxy_pass      http://domain.com:3000/;
    }
}
```

I rewrote redmine's `config/environments.rb` based on the instructions [from this HOWTO](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_subdirectory_%28sub-URI%29_on_Apache), and redmine properly rewrites static asset URLs, but controller URLS are not rewritten, for ex. settings point to `http://domain.com/settings` instead of `http://domain.com/redmine/settings`.

How can I properly configure redmine to run behind nginx?

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty complicated thing to do. You wouldn't think so but it is. Every single redmine version that comes out has a different set of correct and incorrect ways of accomplishing this. For example, I have a working configuration with (nginx-1.4.1, unicorn, redmine-2.2.1) but now that I'm using (nginx-1.4.2, unicorn, redmine-2.3.3) that doesn't seem to work anymore. Here's some links that may be of use:

- http://www.redmine.org/issues/11881
- http://www.redmine.org/issues/12102